# Populating firebase recycler view with multiple order by

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have the address,quantity and medname fields. I need to extract the names of the stores in that address having the given medname and value should be greater than the given quantity.

[image: image description]

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(address).orderByChild(medname).equalTo(medname), model.class)
                    .build();
```

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So you could have: `"medname_quantity": "crocin_10"` and order/filter on that. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thats great, one more doubt, I want to check if the value is greater than the given quantity,how do I check that,say its crocin_10,quantity is 7, so how can I check if the value,that is 10, is greater than quantity, 7?

Comment: You'll want to use a fixed length to store the quantities, so `crocin_010`. With that you can use `orderByChild("medname_quantity ').startAt("crocin_007")`. There's also an example of that in my linked answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Oh thank you soo much,i was stuck at this since so long,finally got the answer,thank you soo much!!